# What are some tips to keep a lens from rolling on its side when kept horizontally on a table?

Tags: lens, tips

Assuming we don't prefer to keep the lens vertically when not attached to a camera.

I'm broadly referring to adding some sort of an attachment to keep it from rolling and falling of a table. Or any other ideas that keep lenses safe.

Comment: What's your use case which means that the tried and tested "put it in a bag" isn't available?

Comment: What's your reason for not putting it end down?

Comment: alex- Lenses which are comparatively longer and heavier like the Sigma 18-35 f1.8 tend to become unstable when kept end down; a small nudge is enough to topple them over.

Comment: If you have more than one lens, buy a camera bag.

Comment: Is this a photography question solely because a lens is involved?

Answer (score 2):

Have a horizontal box or tray for it.

Get or make a square lenscap. (Front or rear)

Large lens has a tripod mount: keep a plate attached, or insert a spare hotshoe-tripod adaptor or something.

Two rubber bands and popsicle sticks.

Roll it up in flubber.

Put non-rolling objects (including short lenses kept vertically) on either side.

Put them on a towel/soft mat/felt

If you are changing lenses, don't you have a case?

Comment: 1 more: put them on a towel/soft mat/felt

Comment: It's a **community wiki** answer, so just add your items to the post.

Answer (score 2):

Sugru.  It's a moldable silicon (I think) type of putty that becomes completely inert once it dries.

You can do tons of stuff with it, including making unobtrusive but functional no-roll stops.

I have used this for all kinds of repairs/mods and it sounds like just the thing you're looking for.